# Kindle Fire what is the toggle option in collections under "view"?

Tags: kindle, kindle-app

Kindle Fire what is the toggle option in collections under "view"?  There is a blank toggle switch right under the view options (grid, list, most recent...).   Can anyone tell me what its for?